# using TLLayoutTransitioning with ViewController.useLayoutToLayoutNavigationTransitions

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm trying to use **TLTransitionLayout** with **ViewController.useLayoutToLayoutNavigationTransitions** and then push the transition

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:[self nextViewControllerAtPoint:pinchedStackCenter] animated:YES];
```

I have two different layout **StackedLayout** and **UICollectionViewFlowLayout**, but when I push the view controller I get this error:

```
[UICollectionViewFlowLayout setTransitionProgress:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8f59160
```

My controller implements UINavigationControllerDelegate, APLTransitionManagerDelegate

and I call the transition here:

```
- (id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning> ) navigationController:(UINavigationController *) navigationController
                                 animationControllerForOperation:(UINavigationControllerOperation) operation
                                              fromViewController:(UIViewController *) fromVC
                                                toViewController:(UIViewController *) toVC {
id transitionManager = nil;

// make sure we are transitioning from or to a collection view controller, and that interaction is allowed
if ([fromVC isKindOfClass:[UICollectionViewController class]] &&
    [toVC isKindOfClass:[UICollectionViewController class]] &&
    self.transitionManager.hasActiveInteraction)
{
    self.transitionManager.navigationOperation = operation;
    transitionManager = self.transitionManager;
}
if ([toVC isKindOfClass:[APLGridCollectionViewController class]]) {
    self.transitionLayout = (APLTransitionLayout *)[self.collectionView startInteractiveTransitionToCollectionViewLayout:((APLGridCollectionViewController*)toVC).collectionView.collectionViewLayout completion:^(BOOL completed, BOOL finish) {
        self.collectionView.contentOffset = self.transitionLayout.toContentOffset;
        self.transitionLayout = nil;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];
    }];
    self.transitionLayout.toContentOffset = [self.collectionView toContentOffsetForLayout:self.transitionLayout indexPaths:@[self.currentPinchedItem] placement:TLTransitionLayoutIndexPathPlacementTop];
    [self.collectionView finishInteractiveTransition];
}
return transitionManager;
```

}

What I'm trying to achieve is something like the photo app on the iPad, where you have different sections with stacked cells, and on pinch or click they expands in a flow layout, but with the clicked section scrolled on top of the grid. That is why I'm using your TLTransitionLayoutIndexPathPlacementTop.
I want to use a

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:[self nextViewControllerAtPoint:pinchedStackCenter] animated:YES];
```

because I want to have two view controller to handle the different needs of the view and want different navbar items for each.

Comment: The transition caused by setting `useLayoutToLayoutNavigationTransitions` to `YES` doesn't call `collectionView:transitionLayoutForOldLayout:newLayout:`, so how are you inserting `TLTransitionLayout` into the process?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that the `useLayoutToLayoutNavigationTransitions` behavior is a Core Animation-based transition and, therefore , doesn't involve a transition layout. Tell me what specific features of TLLayoutTransitioning you're after and maybe I can help.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I've updated the question with more details

Comment: It seems like you're trying to perform two simultaneous transitions that conflict. You've got the non-interactive transition due to the push and the interactive transition that you start inside `animationControllerForOperation`. I have not applied TLLayoutTransitioning to a push transition yet, but I know it will need to be based on an interactive push transition. Non-interactive transitions are Core Animation-based, which is a completely different animal and won't combine with `startInteractiveTransitionToCollectionViewLayout`.

Comment: Having said that, if the only feature of TLLayoutTransitioning that you need is the contentOffset control, I think you can use the non-interactive push combined with the `targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset` (non-interactive transitions honor this) and only use TLLayoutTransitioning for calculating the target content offset. Happy to help further once you figure out what path you want to pursue.

Comment: Thank you Timothy,
I tried to play with targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset but without success

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing a similar issue - and it would be great to be able to mix TLLayoutTransitioning with useLayoutToLayoutNavigationTransitions.

On iOS7 it is possible to hook the UINavigationController push/pop animations and provide your own via a UINavigationControllerDelegate navigationController:animationControllerForOperation:

Here's are snippets of what I have working so far.

```
// inside your UINavigationControllerDelegate
- (id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
                                   animationControllerForOperation:(UINavigationControllerOperation)operation
                                                fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromVC
                                                  toViewController:(UIViewController *)toVC
{
  if (![fromVC isKindOfClass:[UICollectionViewController class]] || ![toVC isKindOfClass:[UICollectionViewController class]])
  {
    return nil;
  }

  TransitioningAnimation *animationController;
  animationController = [[TransitioningAnimation alloc] init];

  switch (operation) {
    case UINavigationControllerOperationPush:
      animationController.type = UINavigationControllerOperationPush;
      return  animationController;
    case UINavigationControllerOperationPop:
      animationController.type = UINavigationControllerOperationPop;
      return animationController;
    default: return nil;
  }
}

// another place
@interface TransitioningAnimation : NSObject <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>
@end

@implementation TransitioningAnimation
-(void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {

  //Get references to the view hierarchy
  UIView *containerView = [transitionContext containerView];
  UICollectionViewController *fromViewController = (UICollectionViewController*)[transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
  UICollectionViewController *toViewController = (UICollectionViewController*)[transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];

  UICollectionViewLayout *toLayout = nil;

  if (self.operation == UINavigationControllerOperationPush)
    toLayout = [[SLCollectionViewLargeLayout alloc] init];
  if (self.operation == UINavigationControllerOperationPop)
    toLayout = [[SLCollectionViewSmallLayout alloc] init];

  [containerView insertSubview:toViewController.view aboveSubview:fromViewController.view];

  if (toLayout){

    TLTransitionLayout *layout =  (TLTransitionLayout *)[fromViewController.collectionView transitionToCollectionViewLayout:toLayout
                                                                                                          duration:[self transitionDuration:nil]
                                                                                                            easing:NULL
                                                                                                        completion:^(BOOL completed, BOOL finish) {
                                                                                                          [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
                                                                                                        }];


    NSArray *selectedIndexPaths = [fromViewController.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems];

    CGPoint toOffset = [fromViewController.collectionView toContentOffsetForLayout:layout
                                                       indexPaths:selectedIndexPaths
                                                        placement:TLTransitionLayoutIndexPathPlacementCenter
                                                  placementAnchor:kTLPlacementAnchorDefault
                                                   placementInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero
                                                           toSize:fromViewController.collectionView.bounds.size
                                                   toContentInset:fromViewController.collectionView.contentInset];
    layout.toContentOffset = toOffset;

  }
  else {
    [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
  }
}

-(NSTimeInterval)transitionDuration:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {
  return 0.5;
}
@end
```